# Insurance paid bill outside coverage and sent the bill to collections - Is that debt legitimate?

Tags: united-states, medical, collections

Around a year ago, my dad was moving between insurance companies and was on Medicare in the middle. During that time he incurred a medical bill (actually several, but only one at issue) which should have been sent to Medicare and he's confident he gave that information to the provider. Instead, it went to the old insurance company, who paid it even though there was no coverage.

Now, without having received anything prior, he got a notice from a collections agency for a bill from the insurance company for the cost of the bills that they wrongly paid.

Is he legally responsible for this or how can we find out?